# Model.all doesn't work after I use create(:model) in specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my spec, I have:

```
  describe 'GET #show' do
    let(:user) { create(:user) }

    it 'returns HTTP OK response with expected body' do
      puts User.all
    end
  end
```

`User.all` is nil. How do I make it return the user object that was created?

Comment: puts returns `nil` but `User.all` will never be `nil`

Comment: `User.all` will be an empty `User::::ActiveRecord_Relation` (like an empty array, but you can call query methods on it). `puts` always *returns* `nil`, but prints the value to STDOUT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RSpecs `let` is evaluated lazily. So the record is not actually created until you call `user`:

```
describe 'GET #show' do
  let(:user) { create(:user) }

  it 'returns HTTP OK response with expected body' do
    user
    puts User.all
  end
end
```

`let` does not actually declare a variable. Rather it creates a method via metaprogramming that memoizes its value.

RSpec provides a `let!` method as well that is evaluated at once:

```
describe 'GET #show' do
  let!(:user) { create(:user) }

  it 'returns HTTP OK response with expected body' do
    puts User.all
  end
end
```

Comment: It's not only lazily evaluated, but also memoized i.e evaluated only once.

Comment: @meta the memoized value is only cached per example meaning it is evaluated under each example independently (something akin to `user ||= user()` inside the example body)

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant. Just something worth noting.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @engineersmnky.